# Using Trigger, Is there a way to give all the record permissions to one user (record owner) and the rest users just read-only permission?

Tags: trigger, permission-sets

When the opportunity record is closed-won, only the user (owner of that record) should have the access to edit that record and, the other users should have only read-only access with that record.

I've tried using 'addError' but that's not the requirement I need because I don't want the rest users to see the error message when they try to edit that record. Actually, they don't want to see the edit option.

I figured out when someone said that if I'm not using the 'addError', then the only thing left is to create a custom component/lightning page to do this. I've tried using the permission set but, I'm not sure this is right or not. I'll attach the code that I've tried and there are no errors, still, a gut feeling that something is wrong. Does anyone know some way to achieve this?

```
    trigger ReadAccessTrigger on Opportunity (after update) 
{
    Id currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
    {
        if( currentUserId == opp.OwnerId && opp.StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
            PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment
            (PermissionSetId = currentUserId, AssigneeId = opp.OwnerId);
             insert psa; 
            
            //opp.addError('Error message');
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not change your sharing rules to achieve this instead? Make it so only the owner has write access, and everyone else has read access.

Comment: Sharing rules are the way to do this - Criteria Based Sharing Rules - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rule_types.htm&type=5